# How to make an onblur event not to work in a special div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<input>` textbox and a `<div>` containing the name of cities.

On click of the div's content, I do populate the textbox with the corresponding city name, this works.

I also need to fire an alert when the `<input>` textbox loses focus. To do this, I used the `onblur` event.

The problem is that this `onblur` event will also fire when the user clicks  on one of the *city names* `<div>`, while it should not.

What can I do to fire the alert only when the blur event is not caused by a click to one of these `<div>`?

```js
function clicking(s) {
  $(s).closest(".search_div").find(".country").val($(s).find(".txtcountry").text())
  $(s).closest(".search_div").find(".co-id").val($(s).find(".countryid").val())
  $(s).closest(".search_div").find(".co").empty();
}

$('.country').each(function() {
  $(this).on('blur', function() {
    alert("hello")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_div">
  <input class="country" value="" type="text" />
  <input type="hidden" class="co-id" value="" />
  <div class="co" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="selectCountry" onClick="clicking(this)">
      <input type="hidden" value="1198418" class="countryid" />
      <span class="txtcountry"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Turkey-Ankara</span> </div>

    <div class="selectCountry" onClick="clicking(this)">
      <input type="hidden" value="1198425" class="countryid" />
      <span class="txtcountry"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Turkey-Istanbul</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the code? As it is working fine for me

Comment: The question is not clear & the code shared is not matching with the requirement

Comment: @inaz even then also, i am not able to replicate the issue.... however i have created a fiddle of same https://jsfiddle.net/ks7ksrku/  ........ just have a look into it and tell us, is issue still present in this fiddle?

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't got your comment . what do u mean by setting two timers ?

Comment: this may help - https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: @Kaiido By a bad editing you break the snippet, roll back the snippet.

Comment: @Pedram you're right, to my defense, I had to reload 4 times the page while doing this edit because none of the previous editors took the pain to really fix this question.

Comment: You want to show `alert` by clicking on `.country` but it show when you click on `search_div`, right? this is your problem?

Comment: @Pedram no ,  when the user type somthing on input and then skips from that input I want to show that alert except the part of .co div. when the user clicks on that div although he left the input but I don't want to show the alert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was working even without this trick, so i think it depends on the browser. Here's a solution:

```js
var menuHover = 0;

function clicking(s) {
  $(s).closest(".search_div").find(".country").val($(s).find(".txtcountry").text());
  $(s).closest(".search_div").find(".co-id").val($(s).find(".countryid").val());
  $(s).closest(".search_div").find(".co").empty();
  menuHover = 0;
}


$('.selectCountry').on({
  mousedown: function() {
    menuHover = 1;  
  },
  click: function() {
    menuHover = 1;  
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    menuHover = 0;
  }
});

$('.country').each(function() {
  $(this).on('blur', function() {
    if (menuHover == 0) {
      alert("hello");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_div">
  <input class="country" value="" type="text" />
  <input type="hidden" class="co-id" value="" />
  <div class="co" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="selectCountry" onClick="clicking(this)">
      <input type="hidden" value="1198418" class="countryid" />
      <span class="txtcountry"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Turkey-Ankara</span> </div>

    <div class="selectCountry" onClick="clicking(this)">
      <input type="hidden" value="1198425" class="countryid" />
      <span class="txtcountry"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Turkey-Istanbul</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next script:

```
function OnBlur() { 
  if (!$('.co').data('clicked')) {
    alert("hello");
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.co').click(function() {
    $('.co').data('clicked', true);
  });

  $('.country').click(function() {
    $('.co').data('clicked', false);
  });

  $('.country').on('blur',function() {
    setTimeout(OnBlur, 500);
  });
});
```

Just setting a handler for *.co* click didn't help, because *blur* triggers first. So you should use *setTimeout()*. Also you should add *$('.country').click()* handler to refresh the data each time.